# Trying to extract the max value from different groups in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, groupwise-maximum

I have a dataframe (top_lang) that has a list of countries (country), the different languages spoken in each country (lang) and the number of people in each country that speak each language (langCountryPop). I have the langCountryPop column in descending order for each country and I would like to extract the largest number for each country.

This is a sample of my data:
[image]

A sample output I would like is:

```
x = data.frame("country"= c("American Samoa", "Andorra"), "lang" = c("Samoan", "Catalan"), "langCountryPop" = c(56700, 31000))
```

but repeated for all the countries in my dataset.

My attempt was:

```
top_lang %>% select(country, lang, langCountryPop) %>% arrange(country, max(langCountryPop))
```

But that hasn't outputted just the highest spoken language. Is there a function that will extract the max value within a group/is there another way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: `top_lang %>% select(country, lang, langCountryPop) %>% group_by(country) %>% filter(langCountryPop==max(langCountryPop))` can help!

Answer (score 1):

Here are two `dplyr` solution:

Data:

```
df = data.frame("country"= c("American Samoa", "American Samoa", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Andorra", "Andorra"), 
               "lang" = c("Samoan", "Japanese", "English", "Catalan", "Spanish", "French"), 
               "langCountryPop" = c(56700, 1500, 1234, 31000, 24600, 2400))
```

First Solution:

This capitalizes on the fact that, as you say, the `langCountryPop`values are already sorted in decreasing order, so you know that the first value per group **is** the maximum value. You can subset the dataframe on that value using `slice`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

Another solution is by `filter`ing out the `max`imum `langCountryPop` value per group:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(country) %>% filter(langCountryPop == max(langCountryPop))
```

Result of either method:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   country [2]
  country        lang    langCountryPop
  <chr>          <chr>            <dbl>
1 American Samoa Samoan           56700
2 Andorra        Catalan          31000
```